Are There More Efficient Awaiters for C++ Coroutines Than std::suspend_always?
I’m attempting to optimize a binary search workload using C++ coroutines on a 1GB sorted array of unique random integers to induce multiple memory misses. The approach involves using co_await when accessing arr[mid] causes a memory miss, then leveraging another coroutine with a circular buffer to issue additional requests and overlap memory misses. However, std::suspend_always appears to be a bottleneck. I’m curious if there’s a more efficient way to handle this.
struct BSCoroutineHandler {
  struct promise_type {
    int value;
    BSCoroutineHandler get_return_object() {
      return {.h_ = std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>::from_promise(*this)};
    }
    std::suspend_never initial_suspend() { return {}; }
    std::suspend_always final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
    void return_value(int v) { value = v; }
    void unhandled_exception() { std::terminate(); }
  };

  std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> h_;

  int get() { return h_.promise().value; }
  void resume() { this->h_.resume(); }
  bool done() { return this->h_.done(); }
};

BSCoroutineHandler binarySearchCoroutine(int *arr, int target,
                                         const int arr_size) {
  int low = 0, high = arr_size - 1;

  while (low <= high) {
    int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
    __builtin_prefetch(&arr[mid]);
    co_await std::suspend_always{};
    if (arr[mid] == target) {
      co_return mid;
    } else if (arr[mid] < target) {
      low = mid + 1;
    } else {
      high = mid - 1;
    }
  }

  co_return -1; // Not found
}



std::suspend_always is a constexpr awaiter, it doesn't do anything except trigger the compiler's coroutine suspension machinery, you will have to see if another compiler has faster machinery, or perhaps roll your own machinery and not rely on C++20 coroutines.

I mean, if all your searches suspend unconditionally before every access, they will naturally spend most of their time around that point. You can write your own awaiter that checks if suspension is really warranted (by interacting with your executor(s)), to avoid needless context switching.
